# How do I change my device locale (default currency symbol) on 3.x and higher?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, localization, 3.0-honeycomb

I want to change my device Locale because some of my apps use my default Locale to determine what currency symbol to use when formatting money values. In Android 2.x, I'd just go to the main `Settings -> Language and Keyboard Settings -> Locale` but I can't find anything like that in my settings for 3.x or 4.x.

Any help is appreciated.